# Can I send Symfony parameter on Webpack Encore?

Tags: symfony, webpack, webpack-encore

I use Symfony 5 and Webpack Encore Bundle.

In my services.yaml, I have a list of colors :

```
parameters:
    colors:
        Beige: '#fffac8'
        Blue: '#0082c8'
        Black: '#000000'
        ...
```

These colors are used in a `Command` file, in my `Controllers` (= each user can choose a color), etc.

Is it possible to retrieve the `colors` parameter in my SCSS files generated by Webpack Encore Bundle, to avoid duplicating the code ?

Currently, I duplicate the colors of `services.yaml` directly in my scss file :

```
$beige: #fffac8;
$blue: #0082c8;
$black: #000000;

$theme-colors: (
    "beige": $beige,
    "blue": $blue,
    "black": $black,
    ...
```

Comment: `services.yaml` is not meant to store colors, that looks like a code smell. You should rethink it, SCSS offers much possibilities of solving such a dependency.
Anyway, if you really need to access them from your backend code then, put them in a separate file like `colors.yaml` and import it into `services.yaml` with `imports:
 [ { resource: 'colors.yaml' } ]`.

Answer (score -1):

You can declare your parameters into a JSON file and import it from your `services.yaml` and from your `variables.scss` with tools like `sass-json-vars` (or `node-sass-json-importer` for node-sass and webpack).

Or you can parse your scss file from PHP, injecting a custom dependency injection configuration loader, but I don't know any tools to do this.

In any case it's not properly a bullet-proof solution.

Comment: How would you load a json file as Symfony config?
The only way I can think of processing json as config is through [env variable processor](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/env_var_processors.html) like `env(json:FOO)`.

Comment: Sorry, I remembered a `JsonLoader` for dependency injection that I used in one of my projects, but probably was a custom one. However, you can always load your JSON file in `Kernel::configureContainer` and inject the parameters right in the container builder.

Comment: Another way: YAML is a JSON superset. You can try to load a JSON file directly with YamlLoader. In `configureContainer` you can call `$loader->load('/path/file.json', 'yaml')`